# task assignment in tensorflow distributed process

Tags: tensorflow

I'm confused about the distributed training process in tensorflow.

I think the tensorflow feed a batch_size of data to a worker and then the worker update the ps server,is this right?

But when training , I noticed that the step number in the log may strange.

If I have only 2 workers , I thinks the right process should be some thing like

```
[worker1] step 0 xxxxxxx
[worker2] step 100 xxxxxxx
[worker1] step 200 xxxxxxx
[worker2] step 300 xxxxxxx
```

.....
every worker should print different step to log.

Actually , the log are as below:

```
[worker1] step 0 xxxxxxx
[worker2] step 100 xxxxxxx
[worker1] step 100 xxxxxxx
[worker2] step 200 xxxxxxx
[worker1] step 300 xxxxxxx
```

...
Why the worker1 dosn't print step 200?

I am confused about the job assign.

How the tensorflow do the distribution training?
the chief worker split data to batch_size , then give a batch to a worker then update the ps server?
OR, every worker will run whole data ,and update the ps server ?

#### If possible, provide a minimal reproducible example (We usually don't have time to read hundreds of lines of your code)

```

```
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):
    # Read TFRecords files for training
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        tf.train.match_filenames_once(FLAGS.train),
        num_epochs=epoch_number)
    serialized_example = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
    batch_serialized_example = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [serialized_example],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=thread_number,
        capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    features = tf.parse_example(
        batch_serialized_example,
        features={
            "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
            "ids": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
            "values": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        })
    batch_labels = features["label"]
    batch_ids = features["ids"]
    batch_values = features["values"]

    # Read TFRecords file for validatioin
    validate_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        tf.train.match_filenames_once(FLAGS.eval),
        num_epochs=epoch_number)
    validate_serialized_example = read_and_decode(validate_filename_queue)
    validate_batch_serialized_example = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [validate_serialized_example],
        batch_size=validate_batch_size,
        num_threads=thread_number,
        capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    validate_features = tf.parse_example(
        validate_batch_serialized_example,
        features={
            "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
            "ids": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
            "values": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        })
    validate_batch_labels = features["label"]
    validate_batch_ids = features["ids"]
    validate_batch_values = features["values"]
    logits = inference(batch_ids, batch_values)
    batch_labels = tf.to_int64(batch_labels)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,
                                                                   batch_labels)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='loss')

    print("Use the optimizer: {}".format(FLAGS.optimizer))

    optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate)

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)




    # Initialize saver and summary
    steps_to_validate = FLAGS.steps_to_validate
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep = 2)
    keys_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float")
    keys = tf.identity(keys_placeholder)
    tf.add_to_collection("inputs", json.dumps({'key': keys_placeholder.name}))
    tf.add_to_collection("outputs", json.dumps({'key': keys.name,
                                                'softmax': inference_softmax.name,
                                                'prediction': inference_op.name}))

    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()


sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                         logdir="./train_process/",
                         init_op=init_op,
                         summary_op=summary_op,
                         saver=saver,
                         global_step=global_step,
                         save_model_secs=60)

# Create session to run graph
with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:

    while not sv.should_stop():
        # Get coordinator and run queues to read data
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                _, loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, loss, global_step])
                if step % steps_to_validate == 0:
                    accuracy_value, auc_value, summary_value = sess.run(
                        [accuracy, auc_op, summary_op])
                    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                    print("[{}] Task: {}, Step: {}, loss: {}, accuracy: {}, auc: {}".format(
                        end_time - start_time,
                        FLAGS.task_index,
                        step, loss_value, accuracy_value,
                        auc_value))

                    start_time = end_time
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print("Done training after reading all data")
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            print("coord stopped")

        # Wait for threads to exit
        coord.join(threads)
```

```

#### Logs or other output that would be helpful

(If logs are large, please upload as attachment or provide link).
```

```
[0:00:17.115814] Task: 0, Step: 74600, loss: 0.303285002708, accuracy: 0.910000026226, auc: 0.946377456188
[0:00:03.804889] Task: 1, Step: 74700, loss: 0.287385582924, accuracy: 0.879999995232, auc: 0.946395516396
[0:00:03.778589] Task: 0, Step: 74800, loss: 0.247096762061, accuracy: 0.860000014305, auc: 0.946370542049
[0:00:03.772320] Task: 1, Step: 74900, loss: 0.264987647533, accuracy: 0.899999976158, auc: 0.946406364441
[0:00:03.795459] Task: 0, Step: 75000, loss: 0.228719010949, accuracy: 0.899999976158, auc: 0.946437120438
[0:00:01.902293] Task: 1, Step: 75000, loss: 0.217391207814, accuracy: 0.910000026226, auc: 0.946473121643
[0:00:01.942055] Task: 1, Step: 75100, loss: 0.284583866596, accuracy: 0.889999985695, auc: 0.946496844292
[0:00:03.860608] Task: 0, Step: 75200, loss: 0.273199081421, accuracy: 0.850000023842, auc: 0.946503221989
[0:00:03.800881] Task: 1, Step: 75300, loss: 0.189931258559, accuracy: 0.930000007153, auc: 0.946559965611
```

```

Answer (score 20):

There aren't really official docs besides the [HowTo](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/distributed/index.html) so a good way to figure out how things work is by studying examples.

The basic concept to understand is that there are 3 kinds of tensorflow processes.

1. The client -- this is the Python process which builds the graph, connects to local  master (`Session()`) or remote master (`Session("grpc://...")`) and issues `session.run` calls.
2. There's the master, which is the process that client connects to, and which figures out how to distribute the work among workers.
3. There's the worker, which does actual work. If your graph has a `with tf.device(job:worker/task:0):`, block, then computation in that block should be executed on task:0

When you create new server with `server = tf.train.Server`, the process that's started is both a worker and a master, but it's useful to understand the difference for debugging.

The easiest example of distributed TF is when you have a single client, which starts an in-process master, and multiple workers. Here's one such [example](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2). In this usage, the main difference from non-distributed version is that you do `with tf.device("worker1")` instead of `tf.device("gpu1")` to tell it to execute that part of graph on `worker1`

It gets more complicated when you have multiple clients, as in the case of "between-graph replication." The parameter server example, you have multiple parallel training loops, where each loop corresponds to a separate client which is a python process issuing run calls. To see on which worker  the ops are actually located you can look on the `with tf.device` annotations.

In your example you don't have explicit `with.device("job:worker/task")` blocks in your snippet, but this part is done by `tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(`. Essentially instead of having a fixed device for all ops in block, the code runs the `replica_device_setter` for each op to generate device to place it on. It places all variables onto  `/job:ps/task` workers, and the rest of the ops on the current worker. The code for `replica_device_setter` got a bit complicated over time, but you could use a simpler implementation of it for the same effect as below

```
def simple_setter(ps_device="/job:ps/task:0"):
    def _assign(op):
        node_def = op if isinstance(op, tf.NodeDef) else op.node_def
        if node_def.op == "Variable":
            return ps_device
        else:
            return "/job:worker/task:%d" % (FLAGS.task)
    return _assign
 ...
with tf.device(simple_setter):
    ...
```

When you run this, each python process will create slightly different version of the graph, except for the Variable nodes, which will look identical in each process (check with tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())

When you have multiple clients running training loops, one issue is -- who executes tasks that need to be done once for all clients? For instance, someone needs to run initializers for all variables. You could put `sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables...)` in client body, but with multiple clients running in parallel, this means op initializations are run more than once. So the solution is to designate one worker as "chief" worker, and only have that worker run the operation.

Also, there's no built-in distinction between `worker` and `ps` devices -- it's just a convention that variables get assigned to `ps` devices, and ops are assigned to `worker` devices. You could alternatively only have `worker` devices, and have a version of `replica_device_setter` put variables to 0'th worker.

Here's a barebones [example](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ea1b1bae0a75c4aae593df7eca72d9ca) with `m` workers updating variables sharded over `n` PS tasks, which uses explicit device assignment instead of replica_device_setter

To summarize, in your case `replica_device_setter` makes sure that your `global_step` is a variable that's stored on `ps` worker, and as such that makes this variable shared across all of your training loops. As to why you get the same of `global_step` in both workers -- there's nothing in your graph forcing `global_step` to be read *after* it's incremented. So if you run `sess.run([increment_global_step, fetch_global_step])` in parallel on two different workers, you could potentially see

```
worker 0: 0
worker 1: 0
worker 0: 2
worker 1: 2
etc
```

Comment: thanks! I read your answer twice, it's very helpful, I know why the step printed same sometime. But I have a few questions about it.

Comment: 1) In my opinion,  the sample code I provided is a "between-graph replication" and "Asynchronous training". In this process, every worker run the same training, and same data(regardless of the shuffle batch)， it's without any coordination to other workers ? but the every worker share the same parameter ?     I can understand why this can speed up the training. Assume we have 4workers , when worker1 done a step, then update the parameter to ps server, can tensorflow ensure every worker get before the others updated? if not , some worker will get the old parameter do something useless.

Comment: 2) how to let the every worker just use a split of data? I think it's more useful? is it "Synchronous training" in the tutorial ?

Comment: 3) is there a way to do exactly "global step" ?

Comment: 1. yes, this is "between-graph" and asynchronous training 2. each worker has their own queue, so without shuffling they would be looking at the same data (bad) 3. because they are async, the parameters in each worker are a bit old/stale, but that's ok. 4. it depends. Synchronous training can be slower but can give higher accuracy. 5. don't understand last q

Comment: sorry， I have one more question. What's doesn't exactly the chief(master) do in "between-graph asynchronous" traning? It seems that all worker are the same . nothing difference?