# tf.contrib.data.Dataset, tf.py_func and distributed training in gcloud

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, gcloud

I have the following code to run it in gcloud that works without issues locally with the CPU with TF 1.2 (I cannot test the GPU for TF < 1.3, but works for TF 1.3):

```py
...
device_fn = tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    ps_device='/job:ps',
    worker_device='/job:{}/task:{}'.format(job_name, index),
    cluster=tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps': ps, 'worker': worker, 'master': master}))
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.device(device_fn):
        dataset = Dataset(....)
        dataset = dataset.map(my_py_fun)
        next_tensor = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        create_model(next_tensor)
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...
...
```

When I run it in gcloud I get this error:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'dataset/IteratorGetNext': Operation was explicitly assigned to /job:worker/task:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
    [[Node: dataset/IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_STRING], _device="/job:worker/task:0"](dataset/OneShotIterator)]]
...
```

I guess the dataset should be only in the local device, so I set the code of the dataset before `tf.device(defice_fn)` in order to create that part of the graph only in the local machine (each machine will read the data). Like this:

```py
...
device_fn = tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    ps_device='/job:ps',
    worker_device='/job:{}/task:{}'.format(job_name, index),
    cluster=tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps': ps, 'worker': worker, 'master': master}))
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    dataset = Dataset(....)
    dataset = dataset.map(my_py_fun)
    next_tensor = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    with tf.device(device_fn):
        create_model(next_tensor)
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...
...
```

But then I g get this error (note how the IteratorGetNext is assigned to /job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0):

```
....
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
     raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
UnknownError: exceptions.KeyError: 'pyfunc_0'
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_STRING], Tout=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/device:CPU:*"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: dataset/IteratorGetNext_1 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[-1,3,299,299,3], [-1,3,18333]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](dataset/OneShotIterator_1)]]
....
```

Is this an issue of the py_func if the GPU for TF 1.2 or is an issue setting the devices? Any workaround to make it work for TF 1.2 (the latest version supported in gcloud)?

Comment: The first error indicates you are not running distributed tensorflow but local tensorflow. The second error indicates that your py_func gets placed on ps_device which is a problem. Personally I don't like `replica_device_setter`, there's too much magic happening there, for your own needs you could write your own 5-line device setter and tell it to put py_func locally

Comment: Both errors are running in glcoud, locally I don't have any issues. The first error could be an error in TF 1.2. I have also tried to use tf.device('/cpu') for the dataset and only for py_func, but I am still getting errors. Any link about how can I create the device setter?

Comment: There's example of a simple setter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069059/419116) Note, I would use "`Variable` in node_def.op" to check if it's a variable to cover new variable types