# How to understand the target of tf.Session?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, grpc

The `tf.Session` has parameter `target`, it can be `''`, `grpc://ip:port`, or `tf.train.Server().target`, what is the difference between them? And when we create a `session`, does it mean we create a `client`, if we have `client` what is `server`?

### Update

1. What is the master? Is it chief worker? And what is difference between `''` and `grpc://localhost:port?` I think they are both on the local computer.

Some questions about your [local_distributed_benchmark.py](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2)

2. I add `print(add_op.device)` in `create_graph(device1, device2)`, the output is `/job:worker/task:0`, why not `/job:worker/task:1`? And you create `tf.Session("grpc://"+host+FLAGS.port1, config=default_config())`, if ops is created on other tasks(worker), how does this session run those ops, like `init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()` on your program.
3. If I use `sess = tf.Session(config=default_config())` instead of `sess = tf.Session("grpc://"+host+FLAGS.port1, config=default_config())`, it will raise an error:

`Cannot assign a device for operation 'update': Operation was explicitly assigned to /job:worker/task:1 but avail able devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 ].`

What's wrong?

4. If I delete [runcmd("python %s --task=1"%(sys.argv[0]))](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2#file-local_distributed_benchmark-py-L83) and change [with tf.device(device2):](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2#file-local_distributed_benchmark-py-L48) to `with tf.device(device1):`, the program will output `CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:1`. I only use session of target `task:0`, and don't use any `ops` on `task:1`, so why does program wait for `task:1 worker` to start?

Answer (score 1):

It's the location of session master (the thing that can execute session.run calls).

- '' is local master (local runtime).
- tf.train.Server(...).target is local master (distributed runtime). It has the form grpc://localhost:port
- grpc://ip:port is the master listening on ip

Here's some explanation of terminology (master, worker, client):
[task assignment in tensorflow distributed process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067398/task-assignment-in-tensorflow-distributed-process/41069059#41069059)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I also have so much puzzle, can you help me? see my Update. @Yaroslav Bulatov